# yii2 BaseActiveRecord findAll() conditions greater or less than

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have country database table (like found in [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html#preparing-the-database)) that I test [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) development application. I have field `population` and I want to create a public method in `Country` model to return all countries of specific population limits. i.e return all countries of population between x and y.

I tried the following:

```
// models/Country.php
....

public function getPopulationBetween($lower, $upper)
{
  return Country::findAll(['population' => [">=".$lower, "<=".$upper]]);

}
```

In the CountryController:

```
public function actionGetBetween($lower, $upper)
    {
      print_r(Country::getPopulationBetween($lower, $upper));
    }
```

It returns an empty array i,e `Array ()`

Now I need to know how to set the condition of `findAll` to be like the SQL condition `... Where population >= 20000 AND population <= 40000000` i.e How to add comparison to the condition with using an array?!

*Another side -or optional- question,* Why in Country.php when calling `findAll` as follows:

```
public function getPopulationBetween($lower, $upper)
    {
      return $this->findAll(['population' => [">=".$lower, "<=".$upper]]);

    }
```

It returns an error:

> **Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException**
>
> Calling unknown method: app\controllers\CountryController::findAll()

In other words why must it called statically?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use debug module to see the generated SQL query.

In your case it will be:

```
SELECT * FROM `countries` WHERE `population` IN ('>=20000', '<=40000000')
```

As you can see it's definitely wrong.

Check the documentation for [findAll()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findAll%28%29-detail), it's not suitable for such condition.
Use `find()` instead.

**1)**

```
public static function getPopulationBetween($lower, $upper)
{
    return Country::find()
        ->where(['and', "population>=$lower", "id<=$upper"])
        ->all();
}
```

Note that in this case quoting and escaping won't be applied.

**2)**

```
public static function getPopulationBetween($lower, $upper)
{
    return Country::find()
        ->where(['>=', 'population', $lower])
        ->andWhere(['<=', 'population', $upper])
        ->all();
}
```

Also change declaration of the method to `static` since it's not dependent on object instance.

Please read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#where) and [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail) sections of official documentation to understand how `where` part of query is constructed.

Maybe it's better to put this method in customized query class. You can read about it [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#customizing-query-classes).

The answer for your additional question: you should not call `findAll()` in object context because it's static method by framework design.

Check the `yii\db\BaseActiveRecord`:

```
public static function findAll($condition)
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i achieve this `$userDtls = Student::model ()->findAllByAttributes ( array (
                    'id' => explode ( ",", $_POST ['studentIds'] ) 
            ) );` in yii2

Comment: @MikeRoss `Student::findAll(['id' => $studentIds]);` should be enough. Don't forget to check existence of data from `$_POST` and validate it before using.You should never trust data coming from `$_POST`.

Comment: so you mean i should do something like this `$id = $_POST['keylist'];  $result = Users::findAll($id);` but its not working and i still get only 1 data of  first `id`

Comment: Actually `Student::findAll($studentIds);` is enough. It should work, I'd recommend to create separate search model and use it with validation. But it's kind of different question, you can create new question and I will try to explain you there. In your example you are still directly accessing `$_POST` without any checks or validation.

Comment: but what should i define in `$studentIds` there is nothing in `$studentIds`.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856991/how-to-use-findall-in-yii2

Comment: Obviously there should be an array of ids.

Comment: yeah something like this `$studentIds = $_POST['keylist'];` but its not working its not returning array in `[1,5,8,10]` format.