# How to use findAll() in yii2?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to know how can i get all data of `user` with array id for `where` condition

In `yii` you could do something like this

```
$students = Student::model()->findAll("id IN ({$_POST['studentIds']})");
```

or

```
$userDtls = Student::model ()->findAllByAttributes ( array (
                    'id' => explode ( ",", $_POST ['studentIds'] ) 
            ) );
```

Now in `yii2` `CDbCriteria` is not there, so which approach should i use to achieve same thing??

I have tried this but it only returns data for first id in the array

```
$result = Users::findAll([ 'id'=> $_POST ['keylist']]);
```

In documentation it is written that we can use this

```
$result = Users::findAll([1,488,489]);
```

But my array `$_POST['keylist']` is something like this

```
keylist{
   0='1'
   1='5'
   2='8'
}
```

I have also tried this

```
$ids = \Yii::$app->request->post('keylist', []);

$result = Users::findAll($ids);
```

And still returns data for first id in the array here is the screenshot

[image]

Thats why it doesnt work i guess

thank you

Comment: You can try this `$result = User::find()->where(['id' => [10, 11, 12]])->all();` it is equivalent to `findAll()`.

Comment: @gamitg yeah you are right but i want to pass `id` which  comes in `$_POST['keylist']` into `User::findAll($_POST['keylist'])` but it only returns data for first `id` in `$_POST['keylist']`

Comment: @gamitg It's just a longer variation, makes no difference.

Comment: @MikeRoss it can't return data for first id. It will always return an array. Check the coming ids and data in database.

Comment: It's better to post text here instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$users = Users::findAll($ids);` is a correct approach.

See what you can pass in `$ids` in official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findAll%28%29-detail).

As I explained you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894148/yii2-baseactiverecord-findall-condtions-greater-or-less-than), you should never trust data from `$_POST` and check it for existence and validate before using.

Example of getting and check for existence with Yii2:

```
$ids = \Yii::$app->request->post('ids');
```

Or just:

```
$ids = isset($_POST['ids']) ? $_POST['ids'] : null;
```

For more complex cases I'd recommend to create separate search model and use it with validation, see Gii's CRUD for example.

**UPDATE:** Pay attention to what you actually pass as `$ids`.

Comment: thank you for your replay but its not working .. i did what you wrote here `$ids = \Yii::$app->request->post('keylist', []); $result = Users::findAll($ids);` and still returns one data of first id

Comment: Could you post what it returns? And what's the value of `$ids`?

Comment: So the problem is not related with code logic, check `$ids` value and records in database.

Comment: @MikeRoss Most likely the records with other two ids simply doesn't exist in database.

Comment: got it... I was passing the `rowid` in `keylist` instead of `userid` of that checked column.. Thank you for your replay

Comment: @MikeRoss Glad to help.

Comment: ok i am stuck again.. do you know any documentation where i can find how to get data of selected column from gridview yii2? let me know thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$students_ids = Yii::$app->request->post('studentIds');
if(isset($students_ids)) {
     $result = Users::find()->where(['in','id',$students_ids])->all();
}

var_dump($result)
```

Try like this